# Simultaneous multi-model predictions in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Here's the situation I'm working with. I've got ONE model but of a bunch of different pre-trained sets of weights for this model. I need to iterate through all these sets of weights and make a prediction for the same input once for each set of weights. I am currently doing this basically as follows:

```py
def ModelIterator(model,pastModelWeights,modelInput):

    elapsedIters = len(pastModelWeights)
    outputs = []

    for t in range(elapsedIters):
            iterModel = model #This is just a Keras model object with no pre-set weights
            iterModel.set_weights(pastModelWeights[t])
            iterOutput = iterModel.predict(x=modelInput)
            outputs.append(iterOutput)

    return outputs
```

As you can see, this is really just a single model whose weights I'm changing for each iteration t in order to make predictions on the same input each time. Each prediction is very fast, but I need to do this with many (thousands) sets of weights, and as elapsedIters increases, this loop becomes quite slow.

So the question is, can I parallelize this process? Instead of setting the model's weights for each t and generating predictions in series, is there a relatively simple (heh...) way any of you know of to make these predictions simultaneously?

Comment: How about using something like apache beam ParDo to make it parallel?  Secondly, I'd trade space for memory here differently.  You're overwriting those weights in each iteration.  I would try and make that a more distributed process.  I've only used beam in the context of tensorflow transform but I know it can do generalized parallel processing.

Comment: Thank you for the lightning fast response! I've been looking into this and it may work for me. Thanks for the recommendation 